# Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on a static property in a Singleton?

Tags: wpf

New to WPF and struggling with the following:

A StatusBarItem displays a simple timer (seconds since window loaded). The binding source property and backing DispatcherTimer are sitting in a Singleton class and are static, which seems reasonable as there is only one StatusBar per application. The class implements INotifyPropertyChanged as it's a one-way binding to the StatusBarItem.

WPF 4.5 can bind to static properties, using static events ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#static_properties)).

This does not work because INotifyPropertyChanged is not static, so the event cannot be static, so the property cannot be static. The solution is to keep the timer static, but make the property not static.

What is the point of introducing binding to static properties in 4.5 if they cannot rely on INotifyPropertyChanged? Is there a static version of INotifyPropertyChanged? I must be missing something, but don't know what. Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing something, the page you link to describes how you define events that notify WPF that a static property has changed.

For a property named MyProperty, either create an Event as below

```
public static event EventHandler MyPropertyChanged;
```

or a generic event called

```
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged
```

InotifyPropertyChanged is NOT used for static properties only one of the aboved named events

Comment: Thanks. I'll blame the documentation that repeats INotifyPropertyChanged like a mantra, but never says to avoid it for static properties.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, just declare events like in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the static property in an instance property, but the design is the true problem here.  Why have static properties in a singleton?  By definition, there should only be one instance of a singleton in a process, making static properties (other than a static property to hold the instance of the singleton) pointless.

Comment: Fair point. It was living happily as a static class in the WinForm world and had to become a singleton in WPF because of binding